# .NET 2.0 application ('Any CPU') running slow on 64-bit OS/processoer 

Tags: performance, .net-2.0, 64-bit, 32-bit

My Windows application is deveoped on [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 2.0 Framework and is build using 'Any CPU', development enviroment is 32-bit OS + [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005).

Now I am deploying this application on 64-bit processoer + 64-bit OS it is running slow.

But if I build using x86 (32 bit), it is working fine without any issue on a 64-bit processor + 64-bit OS.

I have third-party components like DevExpress, Janus, txtext, [ComponentOne Zip](http://www.componentsource.com/products/componentone-zip-winforms/summary.html), etc.

Why is it running slow?

Answer (score 1):

64 bit will not always run faster.
The short answer is that 64 bit application consumes more memory (if you have an array of 64 bit pointers it will be larger than array of the same size with 32 bit pointers)
More memory means that the garbage collection will work harder.
Read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/08/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx) for more details.

In any case you'll have to profile the application and see where's the bottle neck.
(maybe looking at the GC is a good place to start)

Comment: Hi 
is this good to run32 bit application on 64bit PC?

regards,
Pritesh

Comment: There is a small performance hit because of WOW3264 (The virtual machine for running 32 bit applications on 64 bit OS) but I don't think it's significant.
This is from the second link I gave:
"If you’re running as a 32 bit app on a 64 bit OS then you get all of the 4G address space and all of that could be backed by physical memory (if you have the RAM) even without you using 64 bit pointers yourself."